# How to easy upload file with api framesocket

Tags: java, html, servlets, input, upload

Code:

```
File f = new File("E:\\image.png");
FileInputStream is = null;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.framesocket.com/api/media/upload.php");
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
String fsKey = "***";
String fsSecret = "***";
String fsGatekeeper = "***";        
String mediaFilename = "test";
JSONObject resultJson;
try {
    // Add authentication variables.
    multipartEntity.addPart("key", new StringBody(fsKey));
    multipartEntity.addPart("secret", new StringBody(fsSecret));
    multipartEntity.addPart("sig", new StringBody(md5(fsGatekeeper + "upload")));

// Optionally add title, description, etc.
     multipartEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody("Test"));
    // Add the media file:
    multipartEntity.addPart("media", new InputStreamBody(is = new FileInputStream(f), "E:\\image.png"));

    // Execute POST request.
    httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    // Handle Response
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    String resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

    resultJson = new JSONObject(resultString);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Html-form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Uploading Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>File Upload:</h3>
        Select a file to upload: <br />
        <form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I write web application, which upload files to framesocket.com. I uploaded file with certain path, for example: `E:\\image.png`. But I want upload file used `input type="file"` or any other way dynamically from user machine. How easy do this? Any idea?